how to implement a sliding time-window aggregator with Spring-Integration DSL?
I have an InboundChannelAdapter receiving heartbeat messages from external processes. Each external process sends a  heartbeat message every 10 secs to that inbound adapter with its process-name as the heartbeat message payload.
I want my DSL integration-flow aggregator to produce a message with a list of "alive" process-names, "alive" being defined as a process having sent a heartbeat within the last 30secs. The aggregator should produce a new output message (with a list of "alive" process-names) each time it acquires a new/unknown "alive" process or loses an existing/known one.
